# Reactjs : AXIOS with udemy api

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

i want to connect my reactjs compenent with udemy API by using AXIOS, i have the Client Id and the  Client Secret for the api, when i use jsonplaceholder i use the code bellow:

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').
then(res => {
   console.log(res.data) 
});
```

-For udemy i think i used this code, but it doesn't work

```
    axios.get('https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ZDRU...== }})
    .then(res => {
       console.log(res)
    })
```

Comment: Be spicific as to what doesn't work and provide with the error.

Comment: Did you find a way to get their categories, subcategories and topics?